# Calculate the azimuth of a line between two points in a negative coordinate system

Tags: python, orientation

I have a problem that I cannot seem to work out.  I also cannot find a solution already given on any prior posts.

I am working in a metric coordinate system where all of the variables are negative values (example: `origin = -2,-2; north = -2,-1; east = -1,-2; south = -2, -3, west = -3,-2`).  It's a southern hemisphere coordinate system.  I need to calculate the azimuth orientation and slope of a line that passes through two points, given that the first point is the origin point.

I have been able to write a script using Python that calculates the orientations (0-360 degrees) for each pair of points, but a number of the values are 180 degrees opposite, according to a reference data set that I am comparing my results against, which already has these values calculated.

If I use ATAN2 and then convert radians to degrees does it matter which quadrant on a 2D graph the line passes through?  DO I need to add or subtract 0,90,180,270, or 360 depending on the quadrant?  I think this is my problem, but I am not sure.

Lastly, the above assumes that I am making the calculations for orientation and slope in 2D spaces, respectively.  Is there a more parsimonious way to calculate these variables within 3D space?

I've attached my current block of code that includes the calculation of the azimuth angles per quadrant.  I would really appreciate any help you all can provide.

```
    dn = north_2 - north_1
    de = east_2 - east_1
    x = x + 1


    if dn<0 and de<=0:
        q = "q3"
        theta = math.degrees(math.atan2(dn,de))
        orientation = 90- theta
    if dn>=0 and de <0:
        q = "q4"
        theta = math.degrees(math.atan2(dn,de))
        orientation = 270-theta
    if dn>0 and de>=0:
        q = "q1"
        theta = math.degrees(math.atan2(dn,de))
        orientation = 270-theta
    if dn<=0 and de>0:
        q = "q2"
        theta = math.degrees(math.atan2(dn,de))
        orientation = 90-theta
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is exactly, but you'll probably find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system useful.

Comment: What do you mean by 'metric coordinate system'? Do you mean Cartesian? Or are you doing something weird with a metric tensor?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  By metric coordinate system I meant one that relies on metric values (like UTM) and not on an earth-centered / earth-fixed angular coordinate system like latitude and longitude.  After quite a bit of fussing though I figured out the issue.  I had to rotate the output in radians and then convert it to degrees